# How can I resolve webpack-dev-server setting error in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I set it up as below image. (for Vue.js Project)

[image]

And when I run the server, I see below error.

(node:23756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Class constructor ServeCommand cannot be invoked without 'new'

[image]

how can I resolve this error?

I want to use the server without any problems.